# ZKM 15 Deobfuscation (Jar file)

Tags: decompilation, deobfuscation

Hello I am looking for someone who can deobfuscate a ZKM 15 obfuscated jar file for me.
I am willing to pay money for this.

I mostly just need Strings from the jar file. It doesn't need to be perfect.

Add me and message me on discord:
Bryside#0001